# Is it possible to get a function name without invoking it?

Tags: c

How can i get a function's name without calling/invoking it, or is that even possible ?

I have an array of sorting functions, my goal is to be able to list the name of each one, dynamically, without having to invoke any.
After searching on the web, i couldn't find any solution that doesn't require the function being invoked and uses `__FUNCTION__` or `__func__`.

The array of functions that is use:

```c
// Pointer to functions
char *(*srtFunc[])(int *, int) = {selection, bubble, recursiveBubble, insertion, recursiveInsertion};
```

More information about what I want to achieve with this:

I want to loop over each function in the given array, create a file with the name of the function, invoke the function 100 times with different arguments each time, and print the time spent by the function each time in its dedicated file, redo for the remaining functions.

Comment: No, there's no way to get function names from function pointers. `__FUNCTION__` is a preprocessor macro that only exists inside the function.

Comment: You can always resort to preprocessor tricks with the stringize operator.

Comment: Use an array of structures that contains the name and function pointer. You can use a macro to generate the structure with the stringize operator.

Comment: Function names doesn’t exist after compilation.

Comment: @Fredrik it'll be available when there's debug information or the function is exported. But yes, internal functions won't be available in production binary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, not easily. C is not built for [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) and doesn't have features like this-- the name of function *foo* and the call to function *foo* are compiled down to just some jump and call instructions in the output; the actual name "foo" is essentially a convenience for you when programming and disappears in the compiled output.

The macro `__FUNCTION__` is a preprocessor macro-- and as you note it only works within a function, because all it does it tell the preprocessor (as its churning through the text) hey, as you're scanning this token just drop in the name of the function you're currently scanning and then continue on. It's very "dumb" and is upstream of even the compiler.

There are various ways to get the effective result you want here, including most simply just manually building a table of string literals that have the same names as your functions. You can do this in fairly clean ways (see @nielsen's answer for a useful snippet) using macros. But the preprocessor/compiler can't help you derive or enforce a table from the *actual* functions so you will always have *some* risk of an issue at runtime when you make changes to it. Unfortunately C just doesn't have the capability for the kind of elegance you're looking for in this design.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to do something with smart preprocessor tricks, but your code would be difficult to read. I think I would go for the really low-tech solution here and just add an array of the function names matching the array of function pointers:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE(A) (sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]))

// Pointer to functions
    char *(*srtFunc[])(int *, int) = {selection, bubble, recursiveBubble, insertion, recursiveInsertion};
    const char *srtFuncNames[] = {"selection", "bubble", "recursiveBubble", "insertion", "recursiveInsertion"};
    _Static_assert(ARRAY_SIZE(srtFuncNames)==ARRAY_SIZE(srtFunc), "Function table and names out of synch!");
```

Having the two definitions just after each other makes it easy to keep them synchronized and the code is easy to read. The `_Static_assert` (available from C11) will help remembering to add new names as new functions are added.

Alternatively, a structure can be defined holding a function pointer and corresponding name. This can be initialized using a macro as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *(*srtFunc)(int *, int);
    const char *srtName;
} sortMethod;

#define SORT_METHOD(S) {(S), #S}

sortMethod methods[] = {
    SORT_METHOD(selection),
    SORT_METHOD(bubble),
    SORT_METHOD(recursiveBubble),
    SORT_METHOD(insertion),
    SORT_METHOD(recursiveInsertion)
};
```

Comment: this is a bad way since you need to declare the function name twice. Using the stringize operator inside a macro is better

Comment: @phuclv This is not a situation where there is a single "best" solution. I have presented a possible solution which I would prefer in my professional work where other persons may need to read and maintain my code. You may present another solution which you prefer, but your opinion about this solution is subjective and I do not share it.

Comment: This is indeed a workaround, but a very heavy one, you have to explicitly do everything yourself, which is not good.

Comment: Very well, as I can see the demand is popular, I have added an alternative solution where the name of each function only needs to be entered once.